# matplotlib fill_between throwing an error : TypeError

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a graph as follows:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(rainfall_df["Date"], rainfall_df["Rain"], label = "Rainfall")
```

Where the df type info is as follows:

```
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Date    199 non-null datetime64[ns]
Rain    199 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
```

The graph is plotted as follows:

[image]

I then try and fill the area below the graph as follows:

```
plt.fill_between(rainfall_df["Date"], rainfall_df["Rain"])
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

From searching around, I believe the problem has something to do with the date index, but I don't know. Any ideas?

Comment: It filled in correctly in my environment. Is the library up to date, what kind of data is in ax2, and is it the same when I try to draw without ax2?

Comment: I think it worked in your environment because you may have populate your DF's differently. I figured it out though. See answer below:..

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Turns out fill_between doesn't like pandas series or df annotation... or at least when it comes to Datetime types. I just converted the series to a numpy array with .values and it worked

```
plt.fill_between(rainfall_year_df["Date"].values, rainfall_year_df["Rain"])
```